# Transferring CouchDB .couch files from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, nosql, couchdb, admin

Am currently working on a CouchDB project, and have recently decided to switch to a Linux environment for development as I plan to deploy on a Linux server.

I was hoping to copy over my .couch files straight from - *Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/CouchDB-1-1-1/var/lib/couchdb* - and paste them directly into what I guess should be - *var/lib/couchdb* - But I keep running into file/folder permission errors each time I try to access *var/lib/couchdb*.

Is it even possible to transfer .couch files in the way I envisage?

...

**Update** - Follwing up on Dominic's comments, I managed to apply the fix found in the answer below.

Comment: What are the permissions set on your file/dir?

Comment: They were - drwxr-xr-x - I've managed to change them (755). I knew I couldn't rule out inexperience in this instance. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: How about the owner of the file? Is it `root` or your own username?

Comment: On my account, using sudo. I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: You might want to consider writing your update as an answer to your own question so you can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigative work, I found it to be a permissions error, exactly as Dominic Barnes had suggested in the comments...

The issue is also discussed here - [Staging setup with couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835918/staging-setup-with-couchdb)

To fix it, I first ran;

```
sudo chmod -R 755 var/lib/couchdb
```

I may have also changed the permissions on the relevant parent folders too. I was then able to copy my .couch files into var/lib/couchdb/COUCH-VERSION-NUMBER. After doing that, I then had to use chmod to set favourable write permissions on the newly copied files, but also had to run:

```
sudo chown couchdb var/lib/couchdb/COUCH-VERSION-NUMBER/
```

To open those files up to the user group (the "couchdb" group) that the couchdb installation sets up for internal use (I think...). After that, I restarted couchdb, forcing it to stop with:

```
ps -U couchdb -o pid= | xargs kill -9
```

and restarting with:

```
/etc/init.d/couchdb start
```

After that, everything seemed to work as expected. 
Hope that helps anyone else running into the same problem.