# How do I move MacOS CouchDB data to Linux?

Tags: linux, couchdb, archlinux, macos-high-sierra

I have a CouchDB Database that I have copied from ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/couchdb in MacOS (Which is where the Database data is stored in MacOS) and am trying to move that Information to an ArchLinux System running CouchDB. However when I simply copy the appropriate directory to the path under which linux stores CouchDB data I can no longer connect to my CouchDB instance. (I only have the data, and no longer the Old system so i can't use Fauxton's tool). Does anybody know what changes need to be made to the data to be useable in Linux?

Comment: The standard way is just to do a replication from your old db to new. This is covered [in the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/install/upgrading.html).

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a while back, using Windows instead on OSX.
Moving CouchDB files around should be a copy/paste task.

[Transferring CouchDB .couch files from Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769155/transferring-couchdb-couch-files-from-windows-to-linux/12773060#12773060)

In the case above, it was just a file permission issue (user and chmod).

If you're running into problems after that, then I'd check to see if the file is for the correct version of Couch DB (i.e. the same version on both machines). Either that, or perhaps an issue with a validation or view function.